# List of databases have objects (like views or stored procs?) that reference a server

Tags: sql-server

Is there any script to find out the list of database object that reference to a particular server? I am doing investigation. I would really appreciate your help!

Thanks

Comment: Now that I read this again I'm a little unclear. Are you asking for something that will give you the output of a list of databases, or a list of objects within a database, which reference a server?

Comment: Thank You Dan ! I am trying to get the list of all the objects that are linking to a particular server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to search all objects for a give text string, correct?  [sys.sql_modules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175081.aspx) is the DMV you want to use, it searches procs, functions, views, triggers, etc.  Try the below, with your modified WHERE clause, it will work for SQL 2008+:

```
select sm.object_id
    , OBJECT_NAME(sm.object_id) as object_name
    , o.type
    , o.type_desc
    , sm.definition
FROM sys.sql_modules sm
INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON sm.object_id = o.object_id
WHERE sm.definition like '%somestring%'
ORDER BY 2
```

Comment: I didn't realize syscomments had been deprecated (even though it's mentioned in the link I added). Good point. I can't remove my answer at the moment because it's accepted.

Comment: Thank You Dan and Greg! I really appreciate your help ! Basically I am trying to find out a server that is been linked from other servers to find out exactly what is connecting to the destination server. I am not sure why both of those scripts are giving me an empty table.